# Typing nested property access as a dot string in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to type nested property queries in Mongo.

For example if I have the following type:

```
class User {
   username: string
   _id: string
   emails: {
      primary: {
         address: string,
         verified: boolean
      }
   }
}
```

I have typings that work for single property access, for example the following query would be flagged because "usernametypo" isn't a property of User:

```
const someUser = usersCollection.findOne({usernametypo: "foobar"})
```

The correct Mongo query to find a user by primary email address would be something like the following:

```
const someUser = usersCollection.findOne({"emails.primary.address": "foo@bar.com"})
```

This is where the problem lies. How can I define a type for that query? How do I tell TS that "emails.primary.address" is indeed valid given the structure of the User class?

Edit: It looks like there are some proposed typescript features that might help https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754

Answer (score 1):

You cannot describe this type in TypeScript. TypeScript has no string concatenation or some such.

Mongo is a big thing, if it were possible, the guys maintaining `@types/mongo` would have already done it.